# Does the lamination in a BLDC have to be continuous?

Tags: motor

I am designing a new motor. It would be very helpful if the lamination could be constructed of two parts, so winding would be done on one part and the other part would cover the coils. I am almost sure that it's about what fills the volume, not attaching the layers. Is that correct?

Comment: Add some pictures of what you are thinking about.  In my mind, you can not get rid of the lam-stack otherwise the losses will be super high.

Answer (score 3):

A magnetic path should have as short a length of total air-gap as possible (except in certain special circumstances). That's as true for a transformer as it is for a motor or generator.

In a transformer, the air-gap can be got down to zero by tape-winding, so if assembling from pieces, there's a large premium on having as few as possible, so as few air-gaps have to be made tight as possible.

In a motor, there has to be a significant air-gap between rotor and stator, to allow rotation. If there are additional air-gaps elsewhere in the magnetic path, it's generally possible to get them down to a small fraction of the rotor-stator gap, which will then render them relatively insignificant.

It's therefore OK to build the magnetic path in several parts for convenience, if you can attach them to each other with minimal air-gap.

Comment: Does the adhesive of the lamination count as air gap? And a more important question: the core length is 15mm, air gap between it and the magnets is 0.5mm. What happens if i get another 0.5mm gap inside the core?

Comment: just a note: the additional (distributed) airgap might not be as insignificant as proclaimed. a 100um gap between each segment resulted in around 6% drop in Kt

Answer (score 2):

Part of the design process should be an analysis of the magnetic flux path. Below is a diagram that shows the possible flux paths for a design. Since iron provides a low resistance to magnetic flux, *reluctance*, while air has a high reluctance, minimizing the air vs. iron path length is an important part of the design. In the diagram, the outermost path that goes through "TMR Sensor" is a stray flux path that goes through the air rather than through the stator iron. The part of the iron that is on the outside of the motor between the winding and the TMR is called the "back iron." That is an important part of the path. That could be made form a separate piece of iron, but the air gap between that piece and the iron that is in the center of the winding should be as small as possible.

[image]

Xuyang Liu, Chunhua Liu, Philip W. T. Pong, *Velocity Measurement Technique for Permanent Magnet Synchronous Motors Through External Stray Magnetic Field Sensing*; IEEE Sensors Journal, Vol. 18, No. 10, May 15, 2018

It is best to insert the stator windings in slots as shown below. The flux path is through the tooth width between the slots and to the air gap at the wider part. All of those dimensions are important in the motor design.

[image]

https://www.comsol.com/forum/thread/152051/how-can-i-draw-stator-winding-slots-of-induction-machine